# Is there a general way to process only visible cells in excel?

Tags: excel, cell, formula, visible, calculation

I am wondering, if there is a general way to express, that only visible rows of a formula should be taken into account.

If I have for example a formula `sumif($E5:$E100; "ABC"; $F5:F100)` it would be very helpful, if there would be a way to express, that the given ranges should only take visible cells into account. I could imagine that a kind of prefix can be specified to a range construct like `%` or that `like`. For example the formula then would look like `sumif(%$E5:%$E100; "ABC"; %F5:%F100)` to make clear, that in the given ranges only visible rows should be taken into account.

Same would then for example be for `sum(%A1:%A100)` which would mean, that in the range between `A1` and `A100` only visible cells should be taken to sum up the cells.

The point is, that this construct could be taken inside any kind of formula, no matter what it is.

Thanks in advance
Georg

Comment: Generically to sum sumrange based on a match in criteriarange.....but only for visible rows you can use this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT((criteriarange=criteria)+0,SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(sumrange,ROW(sumrange)-MIN(ROW(sumrange)),0,1,1)))`  The first part (criteriarange=criteria)+0 just checks the criteria for each row and returns 1 for a match or 0 

OFFSET returns an "array of ranges" with each range in this case being a single cell from the sum range. SUBTOTAL can process that and with the sum function (109) gives the "sum" (i.e. the value) of each cell, only when visible.

Comment: use subtotal instead of sum

Comment: can try something like (untested) `=SUMPRODUCT(($E$5:$E$100="ABC")+0,SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET($F$2:$F$100,ROW($F$2:$F$100)-MIN(ROW($F$2:$F$100)),0,1,1)))`

Answer (score 1):

Generically to sum sumrange based on a match in criteriarange.....but only for visible rows you can use this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT((criteriarange=criteria)+0,SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(sumrange,ROW(sumrange)-MIN(ROW(sumrange)),0,1,1)))` The first part `(criteriarange=criteria)+0` just checks the criteria for each row and returns 1 for a match or 0 `OFFSET` returns an "array of ranges" with each range in this case being a single cell from the sum range. `SUBTOTAL` can process that and with the sum `function (109)` gives the "sum" (i.e. the value) of each cell, only when visible. – `SUMPRODUCT` then multiplies the two ranges and sums the result, effectively giving you the sum of visible rows where the criteria matches
Try This

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($E$5:$E$100="ABC")+0,SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET($F$5:$F$100,ROW($F$5:$F$100)-MIN(ROW($F$5:$F$100)),0,1,1)))
```

[image]